# StackOverflowException for nestes configuration elements

Tags: c#, web-config, .net-4.5, stack-overflow, app-config

Im trying to make configuration with nested elemets.
but parent-child relation is one-to-one, not one-to-many.
Meaning **storageProvider** could have only one **nestedProvider**.

Nesting level is not limited.

```
...
<store storeName="123">
    <storageProvider type="disk">        
        <nestedProvider type="share">                          
             <nestedProvider type="amazon-s3">            
             </nestedProvider>       
        </nestedProvider>
    </storageProvider>
</store>
...
```

**Question**
When I create StorageProviderElement with NestedProvider property and try to read configuration I catch StackOverflowException in mscorlib. Like there is a bug in .NET (im using .NET 4.5)

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or it is expected behavior?

At this point I had to change this property to a collection (like you do in any other way) but still I wonder why I can't make nested one-to-one elements.

**Code:**
StoreElement

```
public class StoreElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    private const string storeName = "storeName";
    private const string storageProvider = "storageProvider";

    [ConfigurationProperty(storeName, IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
    public string StoreName
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)base[storeName];
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty(storageProvider, IsRequired = true)]
    public StorageProviderElement StorageProvider
    {
        get
        {
            return (StorageProviderElement)this[storageProvider];
        }
    }
}
```

StorageProviderElement
(this is the one with recursion)

```
public class StorageProviderElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    private const string type = "type";
    private const string options = "options";
    private const string nestedProvider = "nestedProvider";


    [ConfigurationProperty(type, IsRequired = true)]
    public string Type
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)base[type];
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty(options, IsDefaultCollection = false, IsRequired = false)]
    public GenericConfigurationElementCollection<StorageProviderOptionElement> Options
    {
        get
        {
            return (GenericConfigurationElementCollection<StorageProviderOptionElement>) this[options];
        }
    }

    // this is what trigger stack overflow exception
    [ConfigurationProperty(nestedProvider, IsDefaultCollection = false, IsRequired = false)]
    public StorageProviderElement NestedProvider
    {
        get
        {
            return (StorageProviderElement)this[nestedProvider];
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Screenshot showing why the StackOverflowException is difficult to debug.

[image]

Comment: You are causing the `StackOverflowException` yourself. See the call stack in the debugger.

Comment: @PatrickHofman no im not, see screen.

Comment: Yes, you are... What is the call stack?

Comment: Can you add the call stack?
Have you debugged the code to see if the code is acting as expected?

Comment: Could you please be more specific/helpful. What could possibly trigger StackOverflowException here? I use C# since it was invented and can distinguish exceptions :)

Comment: you cant get SOE stack easelly, (go ahead and see it yourself in VS if you dont belive)

Comment: We are trying to be helpful. The call stack would help us help you.. 
Maybe the StorageProviderElement the one with recursion is not behaving as you would expect.

Comment: @ADOConnection it is very easy. Just call a method from the method itself.

Comment: @PatrickHofman excuse me for sarcasm, but see attached screenshot

Comment: Please see the call stack in the debugger, not in the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of this exception is this method of `ConfigurationElement`:

```
private static ConfigurationProperty CreateConfigurationPropertyFromAttributes(PropertyInfo propertyInformation)
{
  ConfigurationProperty configurationProperty = (ConfigurationProperty) null;
  if (Attribute.GetCustomAttribute((MemberInfo) propertyInformation, typeof (ConfigurationPropertyAttribute)) is ConfigurationPropertyAttribute)
    configurationProperty = new ConfigurationProperty(propertyInformation);
  if (configurationProperty != null && typeof (ConfigurationElement).IsAssignableFrom(configurationProperty.Type))
  {
    ConfigurationPropertyCollection result = (ConfigurationPropertyCollection) null;
    ConfigurationElement.PropertiesFromType(configurationProperty.Type, out result);
  }
  return configurationProperty;
}
```

It checks if there is `ConfigurationProperty` attribute on given property and if yes and property type inherits from `ConfigurationElement` (your case) - it recursively inspects that property type again. If property type is the same as outer class type - recursion never ends and causes stackoverflow exception.

So in short - you cannot do this (will throw stackoverflow immediately when you try to get corresponding section, without actually calling any of your methods):

```
public class StorageProviderElement : ConfigurationElement
{      
    [ConfigurationProperty("whatever")]        
    public StorageProviderElement Whatever
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

Looks like a bug to me indeed, not sure, maybe there is some valid reasoning behind that, but I cannot find any.

Short example to reproduce:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        // throws
        ConfigurationManager.GetSection("store");                        
    }
}

public class StoreElement : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("storageProvider")]
    public StorageProviderElement StorageProvider { get; }
}

public class StorageProviderElement : ConfigurationElement {
    [ConfigurationProperty("whatever")]
    public StorageProviderElement Whatever { get; }
}
```

In app.config

```
<configSections>    
  <section name="store" type="ConsoleApp4.StoreElement, ConsoleApp4"/>
</configSections>
<store />
```

Comment: Side note: to see the stack trace of `StackOverflowException` you can run with debugger attached, then when it is thrown open "call stack" window (Debug > Windows > Call Stack). In this case problem is reproducable with a code you provided, so it's not required (but still good to have).

Comment: for sample yes, but its not working for mscorlib exception, or I miss something?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "sample" and "mscorlib" exception. In your particular case, with debugger attached, you will see current call stack in that window I mentioned (lines like "  mscorlib.dll!System.ModuleHandle.ResolveMethodHandleInternalCore(...)".) even though `StackTrace` property of exception itself will be null.

Comment: I realized debugging of framework source code was disabled. Now I can see all the details.